# iptables -L lags on non localhost or anywhere address

Tags: 10.04, iptables

I am trying to configure iptables for ubuntu 10.04 and I have a problem with iptables -L lagging on rows where the destination or source address is not localhost or anywhere. The following entries will cause lag on their row:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 111 -s 192.168.1.14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 90 -d 192.168.1.14 -j ACCEPT
```

while this does not:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport localhost -s 192.168.1.14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport localhost -d 192.168.1.14 -j ACCEPT
```

I feel like this might be due to iptables checking to see if the ip is reachable. If not, what is the cause, if it is how can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `--dport localhost` doesn't seem right; 'localhost' is an address, not a port specifier.

However, delays during iptables output are generally due to address resolution. iptables is trying to query the name for the IP address that it prints out, and this may take some time, especially where there's no match. You can avoid this by giving the `-n` flag to iptables:

```
iptables -Lvn
```